# Why is caching not improving the performance in my django view?

Tags: python, django, memcached

I am trying to improve performance of a view by caching a given linear algebra expression and its corresponding result.

I am using memcached and pymemcache but for some reason theres no performance gain.

Heres my view:

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@login_required(login_url='/api/login/')
@csrf_exempt
def compute_lalg_expression(request):
    form = LinearAlgebraExpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_expr = form.save(commit=False)
        data_expr = form.cleaned_data
        data_expr = data_expr['exp']
        exp_hash = hashlib.md5(data_expr.encode()).hexdigest()
        alg_exp = cache.get(exp_hash)
        if not alg_exp:
            parsed_exp = parser.parse(data_expr)
            eval_data = evaluate(parsed_exp)
            expr_model = LinearAlgebraExpression(exp=eval_data)
            expr_model.save()
            create_action(request.user, 'computed an expression', expr_model)
            serializer = LinearAlgebraExpSerializer(expr_model)
            cache.set(exp_hash, serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data)

        return Response(alg_exp)
```

And here is the client I am testing it with. I am testing it by removing the lines associated with caching above so I am removing `exp_hash`, `alg_exp` and so on so I remove the if statement that checks whether `alg_exp` is true or false and i remove `cache_set`.

Anyways heres my client

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

async def make_request(session):
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/compute/'
    payload = {'exp': exp + '*' + exp2}  # Replace with your POST data
    async with session.post(url, data=payload, auth=aiohttp.BasicAuth('jobpink', 'hello123')) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main():
    # Adjust these values as needed
    num_requests = 5000  # Number of requests to send
    concurrency = 10    # Number of concurrent requests
    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        start_time = time.time()
        
        # Create a list of tasks for concurrent execution
        tasks = [make_request(session) for _ in range(num_requests)]
        
        # Wait for all tasks to complete
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        
        end_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
        
        requests_per_second = num_requests / elapsed_time
        print(f'Requests per second: {requests_per_second:.2f}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

here `exp` and`exp2` are matrices: 1000 x 2 and 2 x 1000 matrices and im multiplying them.

im just curious why i get the same exact rps for the non cache and cache version.

the memcache server is working because when i go on the django shell `cache.set()` and `cache.get()` works.

What im thinking is the client is the source of error. if you can point to what is causing the lack of expected performance gain i will appreciated; thanks